# Mapfile not removing trailing newline

Tags: array, gnu, newlines, fzf

- Sample Data: Tab separated tsv file

```bsh
a.1.58  fadado/CSV  https://github.com/fadado/CSV
a.1.63  jehiah/json2csv https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv
a.1.80  stedolan/jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/370
```

- Following selects one record using fzf, and stores 2nd and 3rd column to an array Link:

```bsh
mapfile -d $'\t' -t Link < <(awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="\t"} {print $2,$3}' "${SessionP}" | fzf)
```

### Issue

In the above command I have used `-t` option of mapfile, but `echo "${Link[1]}"` prints a trailing new line!

##### Why is it not getting eliminated?

---

**Reference**

- [mapfile Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/mapfile.html)

Comment: Perhaps `IFS=$'\t' read -ra Link < <( ... )` might suit your purpose better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your local documentation instead of the documentation found someplace else on the web.  In an interactive `bash` shell session, type `help mapfile`, or look up he documentation for `mapfile` in the `bash` manual (`man bash`).  Depending on your version of `bash`, the documentation may vary from what's found on the web.

On my system, with `bash` 5.1.8, `help mapfile` documents the `-t` option to `mapfile` like this:

> `-t`
> Remove a trailing DELIM from each line read (default newline)

The `DELIM` is set with `-d`:

> `-d delim`
> Use DELIM to terminate lines, instead of newline

This means that when using `-d $'\t' -t` with `mapfile`, it would remove a trailing *tab character*, if there was one, not a trailing newline character.

The `bash` shell has had `mapfile -d` since release 4.4.  The introduction of this option was documented [like this](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-4.4-testing#n17):

> The `mapfile` builtin now has a `-d` option to use an arbitrary character
> as the record delimiter, and a `-t` option  to strip the delimiter as
> supplied with `-d`.

To remove the trailing newline from your data when printing the last element, use `"${Link[1]%$'\n'}"` when outputting the element.  This removes the last newline from the element if the last character is a newline character.

Answer (score 2):

If the input data (after `awk` and `fzf`) is something like

```
fadado/CSV<tab>https://github.com/fadado/CSV<nl>
```

and you want those two fields separately, then `mapfile` isn't necessarily even the best tool. Instead, you could use `read -a` to read to an array, or `read` with two variable names:

This would read the two fields to `${arr[0]}` and `${arr[1]}`

```
IFS=$'\t' read -r -a arr < ...
```

or

```
IFS=$'\t' read -r x y < ...
```

E.g. (skipping the process substitution for the sake of the example):

```
IFS=$'\t' read -r -a arr <<< $'fadado/CSV\thttps://github.com/fadado/CSV\n'
printf "'%s' '%s'\n" "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}"
```

prints

```
'fadado/CSV' 'https://github.com/fadado/CSV'
```